# Distribute in App Store from a country without Online App Store?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I just received an email from Apple to continue the Apple Developer Program enrollment process, but before I do, I want to know some important details.  I'm a developer for a company in Morocco and we want to distribute apps in the App Store, I know that there is no Online App Store for Morocco, but can we distribute in the App Store of another country even though our Apple ID, D&B and Credit Card information are located in Morocco?

Answer (score 1):

If Apple accept your enrolment as a Moroccan based developer, you can then distribute your software worldwide through Apple's App Store.